# Batch Rename contents of ZIP file to ZIP file name

Tags: batch-file, zip, rename

My question is very similar to:

[Rename extracted file based on zip file in Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634784/rename-extracted-file-based-on-zip-file-in-batch)

I have 470 .zip files which each contain two files (.mp3 & .cdg) - they are karaoke files.

The ZIP files are cleanly named (Abba - Money Money Money.zip), however the contents, of the ZIP file need to be renamed (e.g FIK001ABBA_02_-*ABBA*-_MONEY_MONEY_MONEY.mp3).

So,  I would like the batch file to do the following:

- Extract the files
- Rename the contents, of the zip file to the zip file name.
- e.g:
- FIK001ABBA_02_-*ABBA*-_MONEY_MONEY_MONEY.mp3
- FIK001ABBA_02_-*ABBA*-_MONEY_MONEY_MONEY.cdg
- renamed to
- Abba - Money Money Money.mp3
- Abba - Money Money Money.cdg
- The files are then added back into the zip file

I've looked over the similar posting above, however, it talks about unzipping *.7z my files are *.Zip.  Please explain :-)

Here is the code:

```
md textfiles
for %%f in (*.zip) do (
winzip -v "%%f"
move *.txt textfiles\%%~nf.txt
)
xcopy textfiles\*.txt originalfolder
rd textfiles /s /q
```

Comment: Please show the code you have already made.

Comment: please see my code above.  question: do I need to download 7Zip??

Comment: You will need to have *some* zipping software to unzip your files. 7Zip is a good candidate, but WinZip or others could work as well.

Comment: Winzip has command line?

Comment: OK.  I updated my code (I added wzzip -v "%%f").  I should also note I'm running this script in a folder called 'test' with one ZIP file called (001.zip), containing a file called TEST.txt.

Comment: when I run the batch file I receive the following message "file not found *.txt, 0 files copied"

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL 
(SET workdir=.\textfiles)
IF EXIST "%workdir%\." ECHO Choose a directory name that doesn't exist&GOTO :EOF 
FOR %%f IN (*.zip) DO CALL :process %%f
GOTO :eof

::
::  
::
:process
MD "%workdir%"
wzunzip %1 "%workdir%" >nul
PUSHD "%workdir%"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=-" %%i IN ('dir /b /a-d') DO CALL :procren %%i %%j
POPD
:: Not sure whether you want to ADD (as you say) 
:: or REPLACE (seems more logical)
:: 
DEL %1
wzzip -m %1 "%workdir%\*.*" >nul
IF EXIST "%workdir%\." RD "%workdir%" /S /Q
GOTO :eof

:procren %%i %%j
SET filename=%1-%2
SET newname=%2
SET newname=%newname:_= %
SET newname=%newname:-= -%
REN %filename% "%newname%"
GOTO :eof
```

Just a few notes:

- I'm not sure whether you want to ADD or REPLACE the content of your .ZIP files. The code will REPLACE. If you truly want to ADD then remove the `DEL %1` line.
- `WINZIP` and `7ZIP` are different, but similar products
- I use a relatively old version of `WINZIP`, which has a pair of command-line utilities available (`WZZIP` and `WZUNZIP`) aimed at batch use
- There appears to be a bug with my `WZZIP` version (v3.2, build 8668) where the `-m` (move) option will `delete` the directory if `"dirname\*.*` is MOVED into the zip. I'll chase this up - but that's why the RD of the work directory is gated and placed with the MD within the `:process` routine, not in the main routine.