# How to rename each *.7z file in a directory to name of *.cue file inside each 7-Zip archive file?

Tags: batch-file, rename, 7zip

My question is related to: [Batch Rename contents of ZIP file to ZIP file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463489/)

But I am looking for a simpler batch file, as I do not understand that very well.

I have about 600 .7z files. I want these 7z files names to match a .cue file contained in each of the .7z file.

To make it more clear, I give an example below:

File `Crash Bandicot PSX 1995.7z` contains:

- Crash Bandicot (USA) track 1.bin
- Crash Bandicot (USA) track 2.bin
- Crash Bandicot (USA) track 3.bin
- Crash Bandicot (USA).cue

I would like to rename the .7z name to match the .cue file (preferably). Like this:

`Crash Bandicot (USA).7z` still containing:

- Crash Bandicot (USA) track 1.bin
- Crash Bandicot (USA) track 2.bin
- Crash Bandicot (USA) track 3.bin
- Crash Bandicot (USA).cue

Could someone help me out to make a batch to do this?

**Edit:**
This is the script code I have so far:

```
FOR /r %%i IN (*) DO "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%~ni.7z" "%%i"
```

Comment: Also, forgot to mention that there wont be needed to unzip the files, just to rename. Thanks

Comment: This is not a coding drive through, where you place your order at one window and then pull up to the next to pick up your code. What effort have you made to do this yourself?

Comment: Here's a hint: `7z l *.7z` lists the files in the archive. From that that you can find the `*.cue` file and rename the archive.

Comment: Thanks nico. I will try.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Folks here are excited and eager to help you with your question but it's important to help them help you. Consider building a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's important because it shows what you've already tried, your thought process, and what you're hoping to achieve. Also consider using [backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for code sections, it increases readability. For example `41 + 1 = 42` is easier to read than 41 + 1 = 42. Again welcome and good skills moving forward :)

Comment: @bad.boo, delete your answer and add it as an edit to your question.

Comment: I deleted the answer, I am so noob :(
well, I found the must close script. But this case it would be different, I will unzip everything in different folders and then would like to use a batch to create the 7z to match the name of the .cue file inside. This is a script I got:.............

FOR /r %%i IN (*) DO "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%~ni.7z" "%%i"
................. How Can I add the option to match the .cue file inside the folder to create the new 7z file???

Comment: I thought you wanted to rename the file, now you're talking about extracting all of the contents and creating a new one. Which is it? Somebody has already told you what command you need, just parse it's output.

Comment: You are right, I just talked to a friend who has a IT background but not familiar to create batch's. He told me that it make more sense to unzip the files and zip them back with a new name. And then I found the script I found above.

Comment: Most compression programs have the an ability to list the contents of the compressed file without unpacking it. Did you read the help file for the compression program you are using?

Comment: Yes I did, I have done like 10 and have like 600 left lol. It is not easy to do that way lol

Comment: omg many thanks for that mofi, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest opening help file `7zip.chm` in program files directory of **7-Zip** with a double click. Open on **Contents** tab the list item **Command Line Version** and next the list item **Commands** and click on **l (List)** to open the help page for listing archive file contents.

The batch file below uses **7-Zip** with the command `l` with the switches `-i` (include) and `-slt` (show technical information). The batch file expects to find the *.cue file in root of each *.7z archive file and therefore does not use the option to search for *.cue files in archive recursively.

Second, open a command prompt window in directory containing the about 600 *.7z archive files and run the command line:

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-Zip\7z.exe" l -i!*.cue -slt "Crash Bandicot PSX 1995.7z"
```

**7-Zip** outputs the list of *.cue files inside archive `Crash Bandicot PSX 1995.7z` with showing technical information. Now with knowing how the output of **7-Zip** (of version 16.04 as used by me) looks like, the options used in batch file for second **FOR** loop can be understood better.

The batch file below searches only in current directory for *.7z files and renames all files containing a *.cue file if name does not already match.

Insert **DIR** option `/S` (search also in subdirectories) after `/B` (bare format) in case of the *.7z files are not all in current directory, but in current directory and its subdirectories.

Here is the comment batch file for this archive file renaming task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Prepend folder path to 7z.exe temporarily to local copy of environment
rem variable PATH to be able to call 7z.exe without full path enclosed in
rem double quotes as this would make the FOR command line running 7z.exe
rem really very difficult.

set "PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-Zip;%PATH%"
set "PauseOnWarning=0"

rem Search in current directory for *.7z files using command DIR and not FOR
rem directly and call for each found file the subroutine RenameArchiveFile
rem with file name enclosed in double quotes. It is important not using FOR
rem for searching for *.7z files as the found *.7z files are renamed while
rem executing the loop. A *.7z file could be easily processed more than once
rem on using command FOR directly. Better is in this case to use command DIR
rem which first search for all *.7z files (including hidden ones which FOR
rem would not do) and then outputs the names of all found files being
rem processed next by command FOR. So it does not matter that file names
rem change while FOR processes the list of file names output by DIR.

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B *.7z 2^>nul') do call :RenameArchiveFile "%%I"

rem Output an empty line and halt batch file execution if any warning
rem was output while processing the *.7z files in the subroutine.

if %PauseOnWarning% == 1 echo/ & pause

rem Restore previous command line environment and exit batch processing.

endlocal
goto :EOF


rem RenameArchiveFile is a subroutine called with name of the archive file
rem enclosed in double quotes. The file name can be with or without path.

rem 7-Zip is executed to output the list of *.cue files with showing
rem technical information for easier parsing the output lines. Any error
rem message output by 7-Zip is suppressed by redirecting them from STDERR
rem to device NUL. It is not expected that 7-Zip outputs an error at all.

rem The first 14 lines are always skipped by command FOR. The next lines
rem are split up into two substrings using space and equal sign as string
rem delimiters. The first substring is assigned to loop variable A and
rem everything after first substring and 1 to n spaces/equal signs is
rem assigned to loop variable B. There is hopefully no *.cue file which
rem begins unusually with an equal sign or a space character.

rem If the first substring (token) from current line assigned to loop
rem variable A is case-sensitive the word Path, it is expected that the
rem second substring (token) assigned to loop variable B is the name of
rem the *.cue file found in the current archive file. In this case the
rem file name is assigned to an environment variable and loop is exited
rem with a jump to label HaveFileName.

rem A warning message is output if no *.cue file could be found in archive.

:RenameArchiveFile
for /F "skip=14 tokens=1* delims== " %%A in ('7z.exe l -i!*.cue -slt %1 2^>nul') do (
    if "%%A" == "Path" (
        set "FileName=%%B"
        goto :HaveFileName
    )
)
echo Warning: Could not find a *.cue file in: %1
set "PauseOnWarning=1"
goto :EOF

rem A *.cue file was found in current archive. The file extension cue
rem at end is replaced by 7z for the new name of the archive file.

rem First it is checked if the current archive file has already the file
rem name of the *.cue file inside the archive in which case the subroutine
rem RenameArchiveFile is exited resulting in processing of batch file being
rem continued on main (first) FOR loop.

rem If there is no *.7z file in directory of current archive file with
rem the new name, the current archive file is renamed to new name and
rem subroutine RenameArchiveFile is exited without further processing.

rem But if a different archive file than current archive file has already
rem the new archive file name, the subroutine outputs a 3 lines warning
rem and exits without renaming the current archive file. The user has to
rem handle this file name collision.

:HaveFileName
set "FileName=%FileName:~0,-3%7z"
if "%FileName%" == "%~nx1" goto :EOF
if not exist "%~dp1%FileName%" ren %1 "%FileName%" & goto :EOF
echo Warning: Could not rename %1
echo          to "%FileName%"
echo          because a file with that name already exists.
set "PauseOnWarning=1"
goto :EOF
```

It might be a good idea to first insert command `echo` left of rename command `ren` near and of the batch file and insert `pause` in a line between `endlocal` and `goto :EOF` to test how the *.7z files would be renamed without really doing it.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `7z` ... *7-Zip is not using standard Windows syntax for options, but outputs a brief help on running without any parameter or with just* `-h` *as parameter.*
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul` used in this batch file twice with escaping the redirection operator `>` with caret character `^` to get `>` interpreted as literal character on parsing **FOR** command line by Windows command interpreter and later on execution of **DIR** command line by **FOR** as redirection operator.

And see [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for understanding what an ampersand `&` means in command lines if not being present within a double quoted string.